# Need a regular expression to extract the value in "Signature" from this string

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract the value in "Signature" from the below string.

What is the regular expression to use for this?

> {"payload":"eyJjaGFsbGVuZ2UiOiIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJtaW5pbXVtTW9iaWxlVmVyc2lvbiI6MSwibm9uY2UiOiJPQ1dwdjkzSzRMSCtQM0FOQmJDM0NCcHRQMmtES1M5TFZPVGFpWU9wUXFFPSJ9","signature":"hlMKmwJt8f24jv6MluM0W+0Kzxo96XlfM1GDop3CHPgLnLFpLmJ9imHFeCCU5bedA4jREuuQ5Y9pY+AqU5qt5QHAjPrtFyT69PktV8B7e+i9tqXae8haIB5iQUD9ln2yjMPE3XfG8+4jHEnHv7x7dePKr4zRgRTRQj6ZbMBaFGt1nhrDexfwHTiGfwuMGuneHUsBeb/EHjaKyGcOoLNq1xjHijlYVb3C3RF+y04VraN3Pt1mfjG9O+3Jvt3cF1xL4nhQO93ZvZ6UU2a0x74PutXxhfoWaeMiZSG0nCBGVP8WNDil1V00cX1Darpp/Xti6RlJJO+CKESInoBMxIWWYw=="}

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for parsing JSON... Use a JSON parser!!

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I tried the following signature"[:]"(.*?)"} but it didn't work. Tried various other groupings and didn't work too. Hence posted here and got an immediate response. Thanks so much guys.

Comment: @Unihedron How to extract values using JSON Parser? Throw some light pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following regex:

```
/(?<="signature":")[^"]+/
```

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/iV9nH0/1)

Comment: nice use of look behind

Comment: Thanks pal. This one worked - (?<="signature":")[^"]+

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 ,"signature":"([^"]+?)"
```

But you should definitely learn regular expression syntax.

Comment: There's no need to use a lazy capture since `[^"]+` feeds to the end of non-`"`s until it hits a `"` as well. The lazy capture makes the performance unnecessarily worse. And since `"` at the end is trashed, it may not even have to be  there.

Comment: Thanks for info, you're the regexp king ! would it also fit empty signature ?

Comment: For my regex (answer above), it simply won't match if the signature is empty. To change that, switch `+` to `*` and you'll get a zero-length match for empty signatures.

Comment: Yes mate I should learn it. Hope its not time consuming. Thanks so much once again

Answer (score 0):

To get the signature string use:

```
"signature":"(.*?)"
```

The string is in Group 1 of the regex.

---

Here the signature string is in Group 0 of the regex.

```
(?<="signature":").*?(?=")
```